# issue changing UIToolbar tintColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization    
        webControlsToolbar_ = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
        [self.webControlsToolbar_ setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:246.0/255.0 green:246.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

Any idea why the color is still solid black? In my view did load I added the toolbar:

```
self.webControlsToolbar_.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frameHeight - self.webControlsToolbar_.frameHeight + 1.0, self.view.frameWidth, self.webControlsToolbar_.frameHeight);
        [self.view addSubview:self.webControlsToolbar_];
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you show the toolbar? Also, why is the toolbar initialized twice?

Comment: edited the code above, the double initialization was just a typo

Comment: Is `self.webControlsToolbar_` an IBOutlet?

Comment: yes, but I removed that now and still doesn't work

Comment: Any updates on the problem? This really intrigues me, I don't know what might be going on :S You can try to re-start that class because that's the way to set the tintColor of a tool bar.

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding the toolbar via `addSubview` instead of `self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO`? Not sure if that would make a difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change this attribute in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Custom initialization
    [self.webControlsToolbar_ setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:246.0/255.0 green:246.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem before. I resolved it by setting the tint color immediately before showing the toolbar in code. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to set the background color of a button, label, etc. exactly as I want with the utility bar, then create an outlet called say, myOutlet, and do this:

```
[self.webControlsToolbar_ setTintColor:myOutlet.backgroundColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the line

```
self.webControlsToolbar_.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frameHeight - self.webControlsToolbar_.frameHeight + 1.0, self.view.frameWidth, self.webControlsToolbar_.frameHeight);
```

Try to `NSLog` a `self.webControlsToolbar_.frameHeight` property and you should see that is zero after `[UIToolBar new];` Use a constant height instead.

Comment: what does this have to do with setting the tint color? it prints 44 BTW